# Get string in the middle Without Loops

Tags: regex, split

Is there a way I can get the file_name content string, by using split, or regex, combined with substring or something else?

I am trying to get the string `["Teste_Excel.csv"]` and it´s not working so far.

Here´s the content I have.

`{"file_date":["2019-10-30T13:51:05Z"],"file_name":["Teste_Excel.csv"],"file_size":["693"]}`

Comment: Can you at least share what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?i)(?<="file_name":).*?(?=[,}])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/anWrlZKGPmyIVqse)

Comment: It should also work without the mode identifier: `(?<="file_name":).*?(?=[,}])`